# Cannot get helpers to work with emberjs & ember-cli

Tags: ember.js

It doesn't matter what I try, I just can't get any helpers to work. I'm trying to get this working:

`app/helpers/render-component.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('render-component',
    function(record, fieldCfg, options) {
      console.log('*** inside renderComponent for ' + record);
      return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('hello');
    });
```

`app/templates/index.hbs`:

```
{{render-component widget}}
```

The firefox console says:

```
TypeError: helper.apply is not a function
return helper.apply(this, slice.call(arguments, 1));    // vendor.js (line 19908, col 8)
```

What am I doing wrong? My deps are:

```
"dependencies": {
 "handlebars": "~1.3.0",
 "jquery": "^1.11.1",
 "ember": "1.7.0",
 "ember-resolver": "~0.1.7",
 "loader": "stefanpenner/loader.js#1.0.1",
 "ember-cli-shims": "stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
 "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4",
 "ember-load-initializers": "stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
 "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
 "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.4",
 "qunit": "~1.15.0",
 "bootstrap": "~3.2.0",
 "moment": "~2.8.3",
 "fastclick": "~1.0.3"
}
```

Renaming things to `renderComponent` doesn't work either.

In fact, this is weird. Some times it works for only a few items in my list, sometimes it works for all, sometimes it fails... I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with ember-cli: http://www.ember-cli.com/#resolving-handlebars-helpers

change: `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper`

to: `Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper`

the difference is that "register" is for explicitly defining a helper that ember is not automatically resolving by default, namely those helpers that do not contain a dash.  Because your helper does have a dash in the name, the register step is not needed.

Comment: Thank you. I've wasted hours on this.